# Magento 2 - Replace existing Prototype JS with jQuery

Tags: magento2, jquery, prototype-js, requirejs

**default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="Ei_Productpoint::js/productpoint-slider.js"/>
    </head>
    <body/>
</page>
```

**requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            MySlider: 'Namespace_Modulename/js/productpoint-slider'
        }
    }
};
```

**productpoint-slider.js (Prototype JS)**

```
 define(['prototype'],function($){
 // where $ == "prototype"
var MySlider = Class.create();
MySlider.$ = {
initialize: function(amountR, trackR, handleR, decrHandleR, incrHandleR, minPointR, maxPointR, stepR, labelAmountR, checkMaxAmountR) {

        this.minPointsCheck = minPointR;
        this.minPoints = 0;
        this.maxPoints = maxPointR;
        this.pointStep = stepR;

        this.mwSlider = new Control.Slider(this.handleR, this.trackR, {
        range: $R(this.minPoints, this.maxPoints),
        values: this.mwAvailableValue(),
        onSlide: this.changeProductPoint.bind(this),  
        onChange: this.changeProductPoint.bind(this)
    });
    },
    mwAvailableValue: function() {
        var values = [];
        for (var i = this.minPoints; i <= this.maxPoints; i += this.pointStep) {
            values.push(i);
        }
        return values;
    }
}

return MySlider;
});
```

**Call to JS function**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var productPointVal = '<?php echo $maxPoints; ?>';
    var pointsRedeem = '<?php echo $pointsRedeem; ?>';
    var time = 1000;
    var time_new = 1500;
    var timer;
    var ei_sider = new MySlider(
            'product_point',
            'ei_productpoint_slider_container',
            'ei_slider',
            'ei_productpoint_decr_handle',
            'ei_productpoint_incr_handle',
            0,
            productPointVal,
            1,
            'ei_label_amount'
            );
</script>
```

Below exception is seen in console.

```
ReferenceError: MySlider is not defined
var ei_sider = new MySlider(
```

Followed [this](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) link, to use something with similar syntax to the way PrototypeJS handles it, but after including the `JS`, its not working in Magento 2.0 and throws below exception

```
TypeError: this.mwSlider is undefined
points = this.mwSlider.getNearestValue(parseInt(points));
```

1. How do I convert existing `prototype js` into `jquery` so
   that it works in 2.0 ?

   OR
2. How do I make prototype js work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UnderscoreJs](http://underscorejs.org/) library was created when RoR migrate from prototypejs to jquery. You may use it to migrate your scripts. For example Class.create is _.create

Comment: So you mean including `undersocrejs` and converting Objects would work ? My custom extension depends on prototype and without converting to jquery, its like a patience test

Comment: it says ` MySlider is not defined`.

Answer (score 2):

First add requirejs-config in `Vendor/Module/view/[your_area]/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
   map: {
      "*":{
        MySlider: "YourVendor_Module/js/myslider"

      }
  },
  paths: {

  }

};
```

class myslider

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'prototype'
],function(jQuery, prototype){
    var MySlider= Class.create();

    MySlider.prototype = {
       initialize: function(options) {
         //Your code
       },
       mwAvailableValue: function() {
          console.log('testing....');
       },
       test: function() {

       }

     };

   return MySlider;
});
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: `requirejs-config.js` is already added. Could you elaborate on how to convert existing Prototype JS to jQuery ?

Comment: I think you have to rewrite class js and make decide to choose between prototype or jquery. Above my answer only for prototype way

Comment: Question updated for `requirejs` and `prototype.js`, exception is `ReferenceError: define is not defined define([ ` and `ReferenceError: MySlider is not defined var ei_sider = new MySlider(`

Answer (score 0):

I feel all code look good except 
**Call to JS function**, just replace the below code

if it helps you accept the answer which helps other developer

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
        require([
            "jquery",
            'Namespace_Modulename/js/productpoint-slider'
        ], function ($,MySlider) {


            var productPointVal = '<?php echo $maxPoints; ?>';
            var pointsRedeem = '<?php echo $pointsRedeem; ?>';
            var time = 1000;
            var time_new = 1500;
            var timer;
             var ei_sider = new MySlider(
                'product_point',
                'ei_productpoint_slider_container',
                'ei_slider',
                'ei_productpoint_decr_handle',
                'ei_productpoint_incr_handle',
                0,
                productPointVal,
                1,
                'ei_label_amount'
            );                                                      
        <?php } ?>                  
          });
    //]]>
    </script>
```